# Identifying Clumps (Segments) of Data for Clump Sort Implementation

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, sorting, pseudocode

I am looking for Clump Sort implementation in any language or its pseudo code. The original research paper doesn't contain any. Since I am unable to find any existing solution (mostly because this technique is quite new), I decided to implement it myself. So as the first step I need to identify the clumps of data in our numeric input. I understand that this might go towards Artificial Intelligence but I am ready for it as I know the basics anyway.

So any ideas about how to identify the clumps in data guys? For now I want to focus on clumps of numbers that are ascending or descending.

For example:
`3, 7, 10, 56, 4, 1, 3, 34`
has 3 clumps in asc order:
`3, 7, 10, 56`,
`4`,
`1, 3, 34`

My question is how to do this programmatically?

(Clump Sort: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=5489222)

Thanks!

---

#### UPDATE:

Alright, after spending some time I've found a solution but I have no idea whether the same has been in the paper author's mind. If it was then we've probably added to the complexity of the heap sort instead of minimizing it.

```
int[] input = { 30, 7, 10, 56, 4, 1, 3, 34 };
List<ClumpStartEnd> clumps = new List<ClumpStartEnd>();
public void ClumpIdentifier(int start)
{
    for (int i = start + 1; i < input.Length + 1; i++)
    {
        if (i == input.Length || input[i] < input[i - 1])
        {
            clumps.Add(new ClumpStartEnd(start, i - 1));
            ClumpIdentifier(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just written to the author of the paper. Shall let you know what I find.

Comment: First, what's not trivial about detecting the increasing sequences? Just compare each value to the previous value, see if it's higher or lower. Storing the boundaries is another matter. Second, I note that the paper abstract doesn't compare with Timsort, which I would suggest is a better choice than Heapsort as the target to beat.

Comment: Many things are obvious and trivial in life. For example Bubble Sort. But will you ever dare to use it in your codes? The same goes here. This solution has a large complexity. See the update in my question. Also this is for a university presentation so I don't have a choice here. (Thanks for the suggestion though)

Comment: It has complexity O(n). Certainly no algorithm exists which finds all clumps in complexity less than O(n), because you have to look at all the data. I haven't read the paper, so it may be that the clump sort could work with an approximate division into clumps.

Comment: I see... So I was worrying for a problem that doesn't exist. There's no approximate division as per paper. So it must be only O(n). Thanks for your time sir.

Comment: Have you contacted the authors? Jeff Wilson - jwilson at io.com
Matthew Caudill - 1.zero.9 at gmail.com
Dr Victor Govindaswamy - Victor.Govindaswamy at tamut.edu

Comment: In fact, it occurs to me that in an O(n) pass you can *create* clumps - take the input in groups of (say) 10, and sort each group. Obviously that's a slower O(n) than just detecting the clumps that are already there, but suggests that the clump sort is "tunable" in terms of what you do in the first pass. As a lesser tweak - if while identifying clumps you detect a long descending run, you could reverse it immediately, taking advantage of the comparisons you've already done.

Comment: @Handcraftsman No, as boost has already done so. I am waiting for a response to him.  
@Steve The thing related to clumps in descending order was also in mind. However I didn't get your point about _creating the clumps_. How is it going to help?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that Timsort would be the sort to beat, but I first discovered it shortly after the paper was submitted; sorry about that.

The OP's evaluation of the algorithm is a hair off. Each time Clump encounters an inversion, it alternates between expecting ascending and descending order. 3, 7, 10, 56, 4, 1, 3, 34 is thus an ascending run of 3, 7, 10, 56 then an inversion begins a descending run of 4, 1, then an inversion of that order begins an ascending run of 3, 34.